# HDFS: How do you list files recursively?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How do you, through Java, list all files (recursively) under a certain path in HDFS. I went through the API and noticed FileSystem.listFiles(Path,boolean) but it looks like that method doesn't exist in my instance of FileSystem when I initialize it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can look at the source for `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.ls(FileStatus, FileSystem, boolean, boolean)` for your version of hadoop - this is what is called when you perform a `hadoop fs -lsr path` from the command line

- [0.20.2](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-0.20.2/src/core/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FsShell.java?view=markup#l593) - line 593
- [1.0.2](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.0.2/src/core/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FsShell.java?view=markup#l590) - line 590

Comment: "-lsr" is depricated, use: hadoop fs -ls -R PATH

Answer (score 14):

Use -R followed by ls command to list files/directorires recursively.

```
hadoop fs -ls -R Path/Of/File
```

Possible attributes for ls command are

**-d**  : Directories are listed as plain files.

**-h**  "Formats the sizes of files in a human-readable fashion rather than a number of bytes.

**-R**  "Recursively list the contents of directories.

Answer (score 0):

```
hadoop-user@hadoop-desk ~/hadoop
$ bin/hadoop fs -lsr /user/someone_else/myfiles

-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop-user supergroup          0 2013-11-26 02:09 /user/someone_else/myfiles/file1.txt

-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop-user supergroup          0 2013-11-26 02:09 /user/someone_else/myfiles/file2.txt

drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop-user supergroup          0 2013-11-26 02:09 /user/someone_else/myfiles/subdir

-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop-user supergroup          0 2013-11-26 02:09 /user/someone_else/myfiles/subdir/anotherFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the hdfs cli with -R option

```bash
hdfs dfs -ls -R /path/to/
```