# Searching all file names recursively in hdfs using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I’ve been looking for a while now for a way to get all  ***filenames*** in a directory and its sub-directories in Hadoop file system (hdfs).

I found out I can use these commands to get it :

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive", "true")
sc.wholeTextFiles(path).map(_._1)
```

Here is "wholeTextFiles" documentation:

> Read a directory of text files from HDFS, a local file system (available on all nodes), or any Hadoop-supported file system URI. Each file is read as a single record and returned in a key-value pair, where the key is the path of each file, the value is the content of each file.
>
> Parameters:
>
> path - Directory to the input data files, the path can be
>   comma separated paths as the list of inputs.
>
> minPartitions - A
>   suggestion value of the minimal splitting number for input data.
>
> Returns:
>
> RDD representing tuples of file path and the corresponding
>   file content
>
> Note: Small files are preferred, large file is also
>   allowable, but may cause bad performance., On some filesystems,
>   .../path/* can be a more efficient way to read all files in a
>   directory rather than .../path/ or .../path, Partitioning is
>   determined by data locality. This may result in too few partitions by
>   default.

As you can see "wholeTextFiles" returns a pair RDD with both the filenames and their content. So I tried mapping it and taking only the file names, but I suspect it still reads the files.

The reason I suspect so: if I try to count (for example) and I get the spark equivalent of "out of memory" (losing executors and not being able to complete the tasks).

I would rather use Spark to achieve this goal the fastest way possible, however, if there are other ways with a reasonable performance I would be happy to give them a try.

**EDIT:**
To clear it - I want to do it using Spark, I know I can do it using HDFS commands and such thing - I would like to know how to do such thing with the existing tools provided with Spark and maybe an explanation on how I can make "wholeTextFiles" not reading the text itself (kind of like how transformations only happen after an action  and some of the "commands" never really happen).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HDFS: How do you list files recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941831/hdfs-how-do-you-list-files-recursively)

Comment: thank you, but it is **not** a duplicate, I need to do it using Spark or the very least scala. Thank you anyway!

Comment: This isn't really a Spark task, as Spark is a framework for processing large amounts of data, whereas you just want to read HDFS metadata. As you identified, any Spark method you use will attempt to read the contents of any provided files. So you would use the HDFS API to achieve this. The linked accepted answer is where you should be looking.

Comment: Also, https://mariuszprzydatek.com/2015/05/10/writing-files-to-hadoop-hdfs-using-scala/ is a short tutorial (not mine) that demonstrates how to interact with the HDFS via Scala.

Comment: I guess this is the best I can get, thank you for that solution!

Answer (score 0):

*This is the way to list out all the files till the depth of last subdirectory....and is with out using `wholetextfiles`*
and is recursive call till the depth of subdirectories...

```
val lb = new scala.collection.mutable[String] // variable to hold final list of files
def getAllFiles(path:String, sc: SparkContext):scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = {
 val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
 val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
 val files: RemoteIterator[LocatedFileStatus] = fs.listLocatedStatus(new Path(path))
 while(files.hasNext) {// if subdirectories exist then has next is true
  var filepath = files.next.getPath.toString
  //println(filepath)
  lb += (filepath)
  getAllFiles(filepath, sc) // recursive call
 }
 println(lb)
 lb
}
```

Thats it. it was tested with success. you can use as is..

Comment: it was 4 months old but there is no answer for this thats the reason i answered.

Comment: if you are okay please care to [accept answer as owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)